# Can a employeer hire me if I have an EEA family permit. What happend if it expires?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas, resident-permit, family

I have an EEA Family permit (EEA FP) until June 2017.

Can I work with the EEA Family Permit?

In the case that an employer hires me, What happens when the EEA family expires?

Do I have the right to continue to work after my EEA family permit expires?

Comment: Who is your sponsor and what's his or her situation?

Comment: My sponsor is my husband, He is currently working in UK. I am looking for a job but I don't know if there is any problem if my EEA Family permit (6 month visa)  expires meanwhile I am waiting for the residence card.

Comment: This question is not too broad. There is a concise and focused answer.

Comment: @phoog there are multiple questions in the post.

Comment: @MarkMayo they all concern the same topic, and they all have the same answer, which is that the right to work flows directly from the family relationship and EU law.  This means that under the directive, the right to work does not depend on the family permit, and the answers should be "yes, nothing, yes," respectively, but under the UK requirements to *document* the right to work an EEA FP is insufficient, so the actual answers are "no, not applicable, no." The UK law would probably not stand up in court, but this seems unlikely ever to be tested with Brexit looming.